# C++ Thread locks in class function override

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, virtual-functions

I encountered a problem concerning using thread locks in virtual functions.

I am writing a thread-free class (say `Class`) that uses a thread lock (say `m_lock`).
This class has a virtual function that is intended to be overridden.
The function looks like this:

```
virtual return_type Fun(parameters)
{
Lock(m_lock);
// Do something
Unlock(m_lock);
}
```

Now when a user wants to override the function, he might write the overridden version like this:

```
return_type Fun(parameters) override
{
Lock(m_lock);
Class::Fun(parameters);
// Do something
Unlock(m_lock);
}
```

Here `m_lock` is locked twice, which may cause a deadlock. I have come up with a solution to this problem --- Put the things `Fun()` need to do in a protected function (say `InternalFun()`), and adjust 
`Fun()` to

```
virtual return_type Fun(parameters)
{
Lock(m_lock);
InternalFun(parameters);
Unlock(m_lock);
}
```

But I am not very content, for the every user needs to call `InternalFun()` instead of `Fun()`, which is a bit confusing.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Re: "every user needs to call `InternalFun()` instead of `Fun()`": that's because the names are backwards. <g> `InternalFun` should be the virtual function, and `Fun` is the function that users call. The standard library does this in several places. For example, the public non-virtual member function `std::collate::compare` calls the protected virtual function `std::collate::do_compare`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a smart way to deal with the problem.